# React Native app doesn't connect with Firebase anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux

I am facing an issue for the last 2 weeks. I was able to connect successfully my React Native app to Firebase and could see the details on the Firebase console. However, 2 weeks back the app suddenly stopped working. All I see now is a white screen. I am trying to capture Facebook Login through Firebase and tried removing firebase code and was successfully able to connect with the FB(So I guess the issue is with Firebase connection).

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.
Here is my code

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import reducers from './redux/reducers';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
const store = createStore(reducers, middleware);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Login/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Login Screen

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../styles'
import NavigationContainer from '../navigation/RootNavigator';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../redux/actions'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import firebaseConfig from '../config/firebase.js'
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import { 
  Text, 
  View,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user != null) {
        this.props.dispatch(login(true))
        console.log("We are authenticated now!" + JSON.stringify(user));
      }
    });
  }

  login = async () => {
    try {
      await Facebook.initializeAsync({
        appId: '1742056282625463',
      });
      const {
        type,
        token,
      } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
        permissions: ['public_profile'],
      });
      if (type === 'success') {
        // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
        const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
        Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
        // Build Firebase credential with the Facebook access token.
        const credential = await firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
        // Sign in with credential from the Facebook user.
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        Alert.alert("Try Again")
        });
      } else {
        // type === 'cancel'
        Alert.alert("Cancel")
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
    }
  }

render() {
  if(this.props.loggedIn){
    return (
      <NavigationContainer/>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
          <Text>{this.props.loggedIn}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )      
  }
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    loggedIn: state.loggedIn
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

Firebase

```
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCWjS5WxFgaBajsWKQPFLbC9QekmyxiO7I",
    authDomain: "bookworm-d8e9f.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://bookworm-d8e9f.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "bookworm-d8e9f",
    storageBucket: "bookworm-d8e9f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1097080341399",
    appId: "1:1097080341399:web:767ce9b106a13ae103bad2",
    measurementId: "G-2JY9B79XCC"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  //firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  //firebase.analytics();

  module.exports = firebaseConfig
```

Redux - Action

```
export function login(input){
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: input });
  }
}
```

Redux - Reducers

```
export default reducers = (state = {
    loggedIn: false,
  }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOGIN': {
        return { ...state, loggedIn: action.payload }
      }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/

Comment: Instead of using web config, use module